# Appcelerator - TableViewRow height changes when scroll on android

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a tableView with custom rows on Android.

Correctly, the space between rows should be like this photo:

[image]

But the first time you open the controller the space in the first row is like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then, when you scroll, the space between the first and the second row is correct. I don't understand what's happening because if I show the height of the first row is the same that the other rows. Any idea?

On iOS all works perfectly.

Comment: It looks like you've found something that works differently across platforms where it shouldn't need to. Thanks! Could you please check if this is a known issue at Appcelerator's [JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/)? If it's not, then create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: This problems is for this:
"If height is dependent on the parent (e.g. percentage), and the parent is set to SIZE, height is undefined"

Comment: This is a very big problem, I'm losing a lot of time trying to cheat titanium looking for a good behaviour

Comment: If this works fine on iOS but not on Android, this is a parity that we try address with high priority. Apart from using a (calculated) fixed height I can't think of workaround, so please report at JIRA with a reproducing test case.